# Select points within a polygon based on attribute value within polygon and point attribute values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, select-by-expression

I have a two datasets - a polygon dataset of buffers around a point and a point dataset. The polygon dataset has an elevation value (assigned from the point on which the buffer was created) and each of the points has an elevation value extracted from a DEM. I need to find out, for each polygon, which points in the polygon have lower elevation values than the polygon elevation value. I can easily do this one by one - but I need to do it for hundreds. I'm sure there's a way to write an expression to do it but I'm not certain how to start that. I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2 or can also use ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2.

Comment: "Desktop 10.x" is nine major releases over the past decade, so that's not particularly descriptive.  Please [Edit] the  Question to specify the exact release(s) in use, e.g., "ArcMap 10.8.2" or "Pro 3.0.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a spatial join between your buffer and your points to get a new point layer with both the points attribute and the buffer attribute. Now you just need to select in this new point layer with an expression like :

```
"original point elevation field" < "polygon buffer elevation field"
```

If you dont want to create a new layer you may use this expression (remplace the field and layer name to match yours) with the select by expression :

```
"POINT_ELEVATION field" < array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Buffer polygon layer', "BUFFER_ELEVATION field"))
```

**Edit**
Just notice that you are using ESRI product, the second expression is for QGIS ( but you could probably use a similar expression in Arcgis Pro using arcade) so the spatial join is my real answer

Comment: Bingo. So simple. Thanks. I was slowly getting there - but not quite. Worked perfectly. Thanks again!